Certbot failing on nginx reverse proxy: 404
I am trying to setup a Mastodon instance on Ubuntu 22.04. I have setup Nginx as a reverse proxy and now I am trying to generate an SSL certificate with Let's Encrypt. When I run certbot --nginx -d pacsa.us -v, I get this output:
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Requesting a certificate for pacsa.us
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for pacsa.us
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain pacsa.us
http-01 challenge for pacsa.us

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: nginx). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: pacsa.us
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 94.23.75.107: Invalid response from http://pacsa.us/.well-known/acme-challenge/LnWLQH7GlWEN4ODIF7Eh_8CLOUGhyOc5ZuHfu9LRexI: 404

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary nginx configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure the listed domains point to this nginx server and that it is accessible from the internet.

Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.

This is what the port 80 server block looks like in /etc/nginx/conf.d/mastodon.conf:
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name pacsa.us;
  root /home/mastodon/public;
  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ { allow all; }
  location / { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }
}


The error  indicates that the Let's Encrypt challenge request is not being properly served by Nginx.
Make sure that your domain pacsa.us is correctly pointed to your server's IP address. You can use tools like dig or online DNS checkers to confirm that.
Make sure that .well-known/acme-challenge location block is correctly configured and accessible. Your configuration looks almost correct, but make sure there are no typos or misconfigurations.
Make sure that Nginx has read access to the .well-known/acme-challenge directory
Manually test by creating a test file in the .well-known/acme-challenge/ directory and see if you can access it via http://pacsa.us/.well-known/acme-challenge/test-file. If you can't, then Nginx is not serving the files from that directory correctly.
Try simplifying the configuration like this:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name pacsa.us;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /home/mastodon/public;
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

Restart Nginx and try:
certbot --nginx -d pacsa.us -v

If I could see some logs, it would be easier to pin-point what is wrong.
Good luck!

Turns out the domain was NOT pointed to my server's IP address. Thank you!
